# How to understand bytes output in python?

Tags: python

I am using `struct` for creating byte like objects out of arrays. Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import struct

a = 1
a = np.array(a,dtype=np.int32)
format_charecters = f'<1I'
bytes_ = struct.pack(format_charecters,*a.flatten())
bytes_
```

The code outputs:

`b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'`

This makes sense to me as I am using `<` little-endian byte-ordering and referring the following table `1` should correspond to `\x01` where `x` represents hexadecimal.

[image]

Now when I replace `1` with `10` I get a surprising result:

`b'\n\x00\x00\x00'`

I was not expecting this... I thought the output will be:

`b'\x0a\x00\x00\x00'`

Also for some random value `a = 1324233699` I get:

`b'\xe33\xeeN'`

Using an [online decimal-hex converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html) I get:

`4EEE33E3`

How to interpret the results of my code?

Comment: `\n` is the same as `\x0a`. The representation uses ASCII characters  and character escape sequences in favor of hexadecimal escape sequences if possible.

Comment: @KlausD. oh I didn't know that... can you link me to some article/documentation where this is stated ...

Comment: this will help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/escape-characters-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The link deadshot gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166266/how-to-understand-bytes-output-in-python#comment111698399_63166266) perfectly explained my question. I am adding a screenshot of the table of **escape characters in python** so that other people can find it even if the 'tutorialspoint' site goes down.

[image]